# How to name a Python file that cosists only of a class definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, naming-conventions, naming

If I have a Python file that consists only of a class definition, how should I name it?

For example, if I have this:

```
class Folder:
    """Represents a computer folder."""
    ...
```

, should I name the file **folder.py** or **Folder.py**? And what is the case if the file has (a) function definition(s) too?

Comment: Python is different from java - file names don't matter.  Name the file anything you want.  Avoid names that are used for modules in the Python standard library.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Python has the PEP recommendations that developers are encouraged to follow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python classes follow the `CapWords` convention as you are showing in your code, then the [packages and modules](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) should be all lowercase, as per the python style guide. Packages are directories and modules are the files, so in your class case, you can name it `folder.py` .

As per Paul Cornelius's comment, I'd like to make clear that these are just conventions. You are not required to follow them and they will not affect the program. Though the python.org documentation asks that python classes use `CapWords` and the files to be lowercase, and even has some indications about the use of underscores and other naming conventions, which are not essential to the functioning of the program.

Comment: That's a style recommendation and is not enforced by the interpreter.

Comment: @Davy M Thank you. What should I do, if the class name consists of two or more words (e.g. `ComputerFile`)? Should I name the file *computerfile* or *computer_file*? As the class name doesn't have an underscore.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you until now. The style guide says "Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability," though it later discourages underscores in the package names; so your class file (the module) can be either computerfile or computer_file, however you feel best makes it readable, but if you have a directory (the package) containing multiple classes, then all lowercase without underscores is preferred, though you can come up with a different name that possibly uses one word instead. TL;DR : computer_file is acceptable, and would probably be best.